# Find limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\frac{X_1^3+\ldots+X_n^3}{X_1+\ldots+X_n}<\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I will be very glad for help  with following task:
We are given $X_n$ which are all i.i.d. $U(0,2)$. We need to find:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\frac{X_1^3+\ldots+X_n^3}{X_1+\ldots+X_n}<\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
It looks like we should apply *Law of large numbers*, yet I am clueless how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but you are **told** to apply LLN and you fail to see any sum related to the LLN in the exercise?

Comment: @Did If I'm reading it correctly, the OP has not been **told** to apply LLN; just **thinks** that's the way to go.

Comment: @ChrisVarghese You might wish to learn to decipher the site's lingo then. The formulation is typical of hints being *given* to the OP and the OP *copying* them. Of course this might be an exception to the rule but...

Comment: No. I haven't got the hint to use LLN. I've done some other exercises and I seen similarities. Now when I see @Anirban Chatterjee solution it's seems obvious. Yet I failed to see that. Feel free to downvote, I don't mind. But  consider the possibility that something thats trival to you may not be to individual starting adventure with math. I know it may be hard to see, but it's worth to try.

Comment: In case your previous comment would be addressed to me, let me suggest that you try to 1. use @ to signal your comments to the users they are addressed to (I read yours by chance), 2. slow down on the vilification of users trying to help you (and having helped you), 3. stop conjecturing the votes of others, about which you literally know, and can know, nothing, and 4. explain how you reached by yourself the (correct) conclusion that LLN was helpful here **without seeing how**. Or do none of the above if you think your approach to the site is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$~$U(0,2)$ and all are i.i.d. So $E(X)=1$. Now to calculate $E(X^{3})$.

$E(X^{3})=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^{3}}{2}dx=2$. Hence by weak law of large numbers we have $Y_{n}=\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}X_{i}^{3}}{\sum_{1}^{n}X_{i}}\rightarrow 2$ in probability. Since $\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}X_{i}^{3}}{n}$ goes to $2$ and $\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}X_{i}}{n}$ goes to $1$ in probability. Hence $\lim P(|Y_{n}-2|\leq \epsilon)=1 \Rightarrow \lim P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n}\leq2+\epsilon)=1$. Now $P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n}\leq2+\epsilon)\leq P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n})\Rightarrow 1=\lim P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n}\leq2+\epsilon)\leq\lim P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n})$

But we know that $P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n})\leq1\Rightarrow \lim P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n})\leq1\Rightarrow \lim P(2-\epsilon\leq Y_{n})=1$. Now the above is true $\forall \epsilon>0$. Hence taking $\epsilon=\frac{3}{2}$ we have $\lim P(\frac{1}{2}\leq Y_{n})=1 \Rightarrow \lim P(Y_{n}<\frac{1}{2})=0 $